# Python stem+requests: Not switching circut/changing IP address when using a session

Tags: python, python-requests, tor, stem

Cnosider the following script `tortest.py`, which repeatedly switches the TOR circuit and checks if the IP address has changed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import time

# pip install requests[socks]
import requests

# pip install stem
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

http = requests.session()
proxies = {'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050', 'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}


def get_new_ip():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password="xxx")
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        time.sleep(controller.get_newnym_wait())


for _ in xrange(5):
    get_new_ip()
    try:
        ip1 = json.loads(requests.get("https://httpbin.org/ip", timeout=(5, 5), proxies=proxies).content)["origin"]
        ip2 = json.loads(http.get("https://httpbin.org/ip", timeout=(5, 5), proxies=proxies).content)["origin"]
        print "Without session: {}".format(ip1)
        print "With session:    {}".format(ip2)
        print
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Running this script, I get the following output:

```
$ python2 tortest.py
Without session: 137.74.169.241
With session:    137.74.169.241

Without session: 145.249.104.203
With session:    137.74.169.241

Without session: 5.189.170.221
With session:    137.74.169.241

Without session: 192.36.27.6
With session:    137.74.169.241

Without session: 199.249.224.43
With session:    137.74.169.241
```

As we can see, the IP address changes every time in the sessionless case. However, in the case where we use a session object, the IP address only changes for the very first request and all subsequent requests show the same IP address indicating that the circuit did not change.

Why does this happen and how can it be resolved? How can I use `request` sessions without losing the ability to switch circuits?

Comment: maybe create new session for new IP. One session for different IPs may make no sense. User with new IP should get new cookies, etc. from server so it should start new, clear session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of...

> **[Keep-Alive](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#keep-alive)**
>
> Excellent news — thanks to urllib3, keep-alive is 100% automatic
>   within a session! Any requests that you make within a session will
>   automatically reuse the appropriate connection!
>
> Note that connections are only released back to the pool for reuse
>   once all body data has been read; be sure to either set stream to
>   False or read the content property of the Response object.

When you use a session, it sends a `Connection: keep-alive` header and will hang onto the connection which causes it to use the previously established circuit in Tor.

As mentioned in the docs, you can set `stream=False` to get around it:

```
http.get("https://httpbin.org/ip", timeout=(5, 5), proxies=proxies, stream=False)
```

Comment: You are right in that Keep-Alive is the cause of this behavior. However, your solution, i.e., setting `stream` to `False`, did not solve my problen. It does not disable Keep-Alive (and it shouldn't do that if I read the docs correctly). To get around it I had to explicitly set the `Connection` header to `close`. Maybe you want to add that to your answer.

Comment: @user1658887, would you mind clarifing what you mean for "To get around it I had to explicitly set the Connection header to close. Maybe you want to add that to your answer."? I'm just a student on this and I would love to learn how to solve this issue